# sql server temp tables times out

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SQL Server query that returns 8000 records, the job runs in less than 1 second, returning all records.  I tried to write the result into a temporary table but after multiple tries, each lasting several minutes, have not been able to create a temporary table.  I ended up killing the jobs.  I rebooted the server with no result.  My server has plenty of resources.  Any idea what is going on? Thanks in advance,

Comment: Is the query being blocked? What is it waiting on? See `sys.dm_exec_requests` - `blocking_session_id` and the wait-related columns.

Comment: Welcome to SO, @user2929902.

Comment: Can you share the code. I'm curious to if you are using a temporary table or a hash table.